# static const double initialization in C++

Tags: c++, initialization, double, constant-expression

I have some legacy code that I'm building with "newer" compilers and running into some static const double initialization errors that don't make sense to me. Here's what I have:

```
//header.h

class myclass
{
   private:
      static const double foo = 3.1415;
      static const double bar = 12345.0 * foo;
};
```

When compiling this code with gcc version 4.3.3 - I am seeing the following error:

```
 foo cannot appear in a constant-expression
```

I've already debunked this as not being static initialization order fiasco, as I believe intrinsic data types have a well defined order of initialization - especially when they live in the same class. As a test I've already tried to `static_cast< double >` the expression, but that produces yet another error stating that only integral type casts are allowed in a const expression.

Comment: Make it `constexpr` instead.

Comment: @Ron "gcc version 4.3.3" - I don't think that will work.

Comment: gcc 4.3.3 has a [partial implementation](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html) of C++11, where `constexpr`belongs to. Can you use a more recent gcc verion?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I am sort of in a "bureaucratic" situation with these compilers. Which is why I use the term "newer" loosely.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`static` data members which are not `constexpr` can only be initialised directly at their declaration in the class definition if they are of integral or enumeration type. All other data types must be given a separate definition in a source file, and can only be initialised at that definition. So change your class definition to this:

```
class myclass
{
   private:
      static const double foo;
      static const double bar;
};
```

and introduce these definitions into exactly one `.cpp` file:

```
const double myclass::foo = 3.1415;
const double myclass::bar = 12345.0 * foo;
```

---

If you have access to sufficiently modern C++, you have an alternative option of changing the in-class declarations to `constexpr`:

```
class myclass
{
   private:
      static constexpr double foo = 3.1415;
      static constexpr double bar = 12345.0 * foo;
};
```

That way, they will not require a definition in a source file unless you use them as objects instead of as values (e.g. if you take their address). However, GCC 4.3.3 does not support that part of C++11.

Comment: Thank you! This is a crystal clear explanation. I think I can work out a solution to this now.